Hyperlink between Google Sheets list and a specific website
I'm trying to create a dynamic list of keywords which allows to automatically search for every keyword in a specific website.
For instance, I have got a list:
The first keyword is "Abies alba Mill."



Keywords
Links




Abies alba Mill.
Link 1


Abies nebrodensis (Lojac.) Mattei
Link 2



I would like to create a system that automatically search each keyword on google in that specific website (site: actaplantarum.org) and then puts the link of the webpage referred to the keyword.
In other words, if I should do it manually: My first keyword is "Abies alba Mill."

I would search on Google: "site:actaplantarum.org/flora abies alba Mill."
I would copy the related link and I would paste it in the adjacent cell (I wrote "Link 1" for this thread), namely actaplantarum.org/flora/flora_info.php?id=149

The list is very long, so I'm trying to find a solution which automatically looks for every keyword and put the specific link to it.
On the internet I there are some scripts that allow to search on Google for the keyword but I was not able to find anything that allows to search in a website and link the webpage related to it.

So you want it to fetch the first google search result?

yes, hopefully the first result will be the right one since the Google research targets the right species webpage (Keyword) in the right website (actaplantarum.org)

Related question: Grab first URL off a Google search result
